# Move pointer horizontally using fputcsv in PHP

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I am trying to write 2 arrays to csv file using fputcsv.

But the problem is when writing the second array it goes to the end of the file and starts from there.

So basically I have these 2 sections to write in a csv file and it's writing in the following way

```
ID      Name1

1       AAA
2       BBB

Name2

CCC
DDD
```

What I want

```
ID      Name1      Name2

1       AAA        CCC
2       BBB        DDD
```

My code is

```
fputcsv($fh, array("ID","Name1"));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($weekly1, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    fputcsv($fh, array($row[0],$row[1]));
}

fputcsv($fh, array("Name2"));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($weekly2, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    fputcsv($fh, array($row[1]));
}
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem. Any help or suggestion is highly welcomed.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry is that downvote for writing PHP as php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should store `ID` and `NAME1` in an array and only after getting `NAME2` save to csv:

```
fputcsv($fh, array("ID","Name1","Name2"));
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($weekly1, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    $rows[] = array($row[0],$row[1]));
}

$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($weekly2, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    fputcsv($fh, array_merge($rows[$i], array($row[1])));
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see. Let me try. Thanks mate.

Comment: Also try to make one SQL query for getting data, if it's possible, then you will do one loop only and can write to csv immediately.

Comment: Yes I agree but the situation is that I have to write multiple query as I am  making a weekly/monthly report.It's complicated :(